# "srcWnd is not defined" - TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, github, tampermonkey

Today, I tried to use TamperMonkey, with a code I took from Github: `https://gist.github.com/drew-wallace/e77d514a568ed378b942e9d0fa142356`. There are a lot of errors. Let me know if there's something wrong that I'm missing. The one that showed just opening it was `"srcwnd is not defined."`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace unsafeWindow with window on line 15.

```
srcWnd = window; // window
```

Comment: Are you sure? `unsafeWindow` is well defined if `@grant unsafeWindow` is set.

Comment: I know, but it worked on my end and unsafeWindow isn't recommended anyway. Maybe you try to put a let before srcWnd - "let srcWnd = window". Are there any other errors besides the one you described?